# DES Encryption and Decryption in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, des

I want to encrypt and decrypt some data in my ios project with DES. I searched the internet but could not find a proper answer of my question. I am searching a tutorial or an example about how to decrypt and encrypt data with objective c in DES. can anyone show me a way or example?

Comment: really, I seem to find a lot of them... http://www.codealias.info/technotes/des_encryption_using_openssl_a_simple_example http://www.stillhq.com/des/

Comment: @AttilaH: if you got dupe, then you should vote to close.

Comment: @Anoop Vaidya: I have <3000 reputation, so I can't.

Comment: @AttilaH: No problm, in a month you will be able to...